# Dead-reckoning vs feedback for motor position control of turntable

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, feedback

I am constructing a small turntable that holds a plastic cup and should be controlled to stop at one of eight positions. (Where it will receive a shot of liquid; think "Auto-cocktails"). I'm wondering about how to move the turntable accurately and quickly, with minimum overshoot.
One method is to use dead reckoning and a stepper motor plus toothed belt/gears. Each position can then be pre-calculated and referenced as a set number of steps. Alternatively a continuous dc motor could be used to move the turntable with a set of sensors mounted around the turntable to give feedback as to where the cup is. To prevent overrun, rather than have just one sensor at the exact position, extra sensors could tell the controlling code to slow down the motor prior to getting the halt command.
Does anyone have any relevant experience on the "dead-reckoning vs sensor feedback" issue? Or any input or tips for the mechanical design?

Comment: You're going to want to close the loop. Running things open loop is a bad idea 95% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to ask for tips on system/mechanical design, I'd say without hesitation that you should go the stepper route. Making a DC servo system that produces constant velocity is straightforward - making a position loop is another matter, particularly one that allows arbitrary windup of the shaft.

If all you want to do is move from one position to another within a 360 degree arc, you can use a potentiometer to read position. The problem comes if you attempt to cross over the 0/360 line. Then things get tricky, both from the point of view of finding a pot that allows than, and making your control logic understand what happens when you do make the crossover. Trust me, it gets messy unless you've given it some thought.

Also to be considered with this approach is the problem of slop in the motor/turntable coupling, which can easily lead to "hunting" at the final position.

The obvious replacement for a pot is a shaft encoder, but this has its own problems. The two obvious ones are cost and (again) hunting. You need a fairly high resolution, and that costs. Also, the simple approach to dealing with the final position, turning off the current to the motor when the encoder says you're at the right place, can allow the turntable to drift past the desired position. So the system says there's an error, tries to correct by driving the other way, gets to desired position and sets current to zero, and the turntable drifts the other way... ad infinitum.

It's all doable, and commercial servo systems exist - but it takes a certain amount of experience and analysis to make it work.

Steppers, on the other hand, can be dealt with in a pretty straightforward manner, with one proviso. Steppers have a limited ability to accelerate, and there's a limit to how big a velocity step you can apply. So if you want fast response, you need to ramp the step rate. And then, of course, once you reach your destination you have to ramp down the step rate to get it to stop, which means you have to start the deceleration process before the turntable has reached final position. Once you realize this, of course, you can compensate, and you can get away with a position sensor for each stopping point, with just enough offset to handle the ramp-down process. It's particularly easy if you set the rotation direction to be constant. If you want to go in either direction, you may need a sensor on each side of the stopping points to provide an appropriate offset.

If you couple the stepper to the turntable with a belt (toothed for preference) you can use a small wheel on the stepper and a large one on the turntable, which gives you very fine control of position, which in your case will probably be important to give the appearance of smooth rotation. Even this is not absolutely necessary, since you can directly couple the motor shaft to the turntable and use a controller with microstep capability. Such controllers are cheap, and their limitations probably don't concern you. It's even possible to do what you want open-loop, since if you don't ask too much of the stepper acceleration/deceleration it will never lose track of where it is. The only problem with this is you need to make an "index" sensor, and every time you turn on the system you need to rotate the turntable until it finds the index and knows where it is.

Comment: Lots of good information here...

Comment: Very useful comments about hunting. But I'm not sure I'll get the required torque and speed from a stepper motor of reasonable cost. I was hoping to get the turntable to rotate at about 1 rpm even with a full cup.

Comment: 1 rpm? Piece of cake. The thing to remember about turntables is that, although they may have considerable mass (actually, moment of inertia is what counts, but that scales with mass), a good bearing system will reduce friction to very low values, so the upper limit on step rate is very high.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1 rps (60rpm). The rotating turntable is more of a counter balanced arm, really, about 30cm in diameter.